# how to have multiple FK in the same table/class with EF4 Code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5, ef-code-first

I have these 2 tables:

```
create table countries
(
int id identity primary key,
name nvarchar(20)
)

create table persons
(
int id identity primary key,
country1 int references countries(id),
country2 int references countries(id),
country3 int references countries(id)
)
```

how should I create my classes and mappings in order **to map them correctly to to these tables** ?
(I use EF4 CTP5 Code First)

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring your denormalized references to multiple country entities for now, you could write the following:

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Country Country1 { get; set; }
    public Country Country2 { get; set; }
    public Country Country3 { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, you'll also need the DbContext:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

    public Context(string dbName)
        :base (dbName)
    {
    }
}
```

This will result in the table schemas mirroring your original requirement.

Note, however, that if you declare the classes like this:

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, EF will create a many-to-many join table which will allow you to associate any number of countries with any number of people:

```
CREATE TABLE [CountryPersons] 
(
    [CountryCountryID] int NOT NULL,
    [PersonPersonID] int NOT NULL
);
```

Note that EF infers the many-to-many relationship due to the collection of People in Countries and collection of Countries in People.

HTH.

Comment: it gives error because instead of looking for Country1Id it looks for CountryId